# Creating Arduino library file

Tags: library

I need to create a library file for Arduino. While surfing the Internet, it shows me to use C, C++. Is a C++/C compiler mandatory to create library files in Arduino? Or we can use the Arduino IDE to create library files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libraries are just text files. Use your favourite text editor (such as Sublime Text, Notepad++, etc. NOT a word processor like Word) to create and edit them. It is up to the IDE to compile them for you. You don't need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino IDE has a compiler, and will in the end compile the library with whatever `.ino` script you'll write. But you don't need any compiler to write a library. All you need is a text editor, and produce `.cpp` and `.h` files.

However when you test the library, you'll have to use the Arduino IDE to compile it.

Comment: Thank you.. So there's no need to install an external IDE to compile library files.

Comment: no, there is no such need